# How to tell network manager not to show wireless AP with poor quality

Tags: 11.10, network-manager, 12.04

Is it possible to tell Network Manager not to show wireless access points that have very poor quality or are below a specific quality level. If not, an alternative that can limit the amount of AP based on the quality for them.

Using both, 11.10 and 12.04 right now.

Comment: Can you see in `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` ap who has poor quality?

Comment: Good question, I'd like to figure this out too :P Only found a link for reference, http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch13_:_Linux_Wireless_Networking, it may not solve this problem directly, at least provides a way to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any commands or programs that do completely what you want.

But wicd does show you in percentages how strong your connection is and should give you a list of connections ranging from strongest to weakest signal. So I know it doesn't drop weak connections, but you'll only have to check the top of the list. Check the screenshot of the menu.

http://wicd.sourceforge.net/screenshot.php

When installing wicd it will replace networkmanager. It's in the ubuntu repositories so you can install it immediately with

```
sudo apt-get install wicd
```

Comment: Give it a week. If no more answers appear or maybe some future changes that integrate this I will accept. Thank you.